# javascript numeric string reverse sort doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, sorting, numeric

I have an array `["4", "2", "5", "3"]`, why the sort function works properly but not the reverse one?

```
["4", "2", "5", "3"].sort(); //gives me ["2", "3", "4", "5"]

["4", "2", "5", "3"].reverse(); //gives me ["3", "5", "2", "4"]
```

Comment: You need `sort().reverse()` for that (reverse reverses, it doesn't sort)

Comment: `reverse` and `sort` are not alias, they are different

Comment: Additional note: Keep in mind that strings and numbers do not sort the same way. `"11" < "9" = true` and `11 < 9 = false`.

Answer (score 4):

From [`Array.prototype.reverse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse)

> The `reverse()` method reverses an array in place. The first array element becomes the last, and the last array element becomes the first.

It just reverses a given array and it has nothing to do with sorting. You can do `array.sort().reverse()`

---

BTW, `["4", "2", "5", "3"].sort()` sorts the array lexically.

```js
console.log(
  ["4", "2", "5", "40", "3"].sort() // ["2","3","4","40","5"]
)
```

If you want to sort the given array based on their numeric values, you'd have to do:

```js
const array = ["4", "2", "5", "3"]

console.log(
  array.sort((a, b) => a - b) // asc
)

console.log(
  array.sort((a, b) => b - a) // desc
)
```

Comment: you've marked the sorting function the wrong way around `(a,b) => a-b` is `asc`. and I'd make a copy before sorting the Array `array.slice().sort(...)`, or the console.log will show only the last order.

Comment: @Thomas thanks. Made it to 2 separate logs

Answer (score 2):

reverse with sort function like this:

```js
console.log(["4", "2", "5", "3"].sort().reverse())
```